# What's the quickest way to get a column into a variable from a very large ( > 1GB) array in Matlab?

Tags: performance, algorithm, matlab, matrix, scilab

Basically I'm running the code below in a loop in order to pull out a specified column in a matrix. I have a feeling that this is where the bottleneck in my loop is coming from. I feel like there is an easier way to do this like matrix arithmetic, but I can't think of anything at the moment. The function below will take the argument matINPUT as the large matrix, and INPUT as the integer offset of the column wanted. The results are placed in arrayOUTPUT to be used elsewhere in the program.

```
// Get size and offset of matrix
[matOffset, matSize] = size(matINPUT); 

// Test if INPUT isnt out of bounds, and return 0 if it is
if INPUT > matSize then
    arrayOUTPUT = [0]
    return
end

// pre-load array for correct size
arrayOUTPUT = zeros(matOffset,1) // generates the correct array size

// iterate through all slots and populate
for x = 1:matOffset
    arrayOUTPUT(x) = matINPUT(x + (INPUT - 1)*matOffset)
end
```

Comment: Have you tried using `arrayOUTPUT = matINPUT(:,colnum)`, where `colnum` is the column number you want to select? the `:` will select all rows at `colnum`, meaning the entire column. I think this should be pretty fast because MATLAB is column major. You also don't need to preallocate if you're doing this.

Comment: Yep @jucestain I'm an idiot. The native solution was what I was thinking of. However sadly it only seems to have shaved off a second per 10k iterations, not the 4-5 I was hoping it would. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the last part of your code it looks like a part selection of a matrix. I suggest you can use an index vector to get the values without using for loop

(Hope this can help)